# Johnnie Walker Green vs Gold Label?

Tags: taste, whisky

I drink Johnnie Walker Blue Label and I didn't fell the alcohol burning my mouth.

Is it similar with Green and Gold Label?

Which one of these two has a better "alcohol burn" hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Gold Label comes with 40% abv, the same as Blue Label, and Green Label is with 43% a bit stronger, I think you want to go with Gold Label.

Comment: The 3% isn't small? I heard that Green Label is more smoky than Gold Label, does this hide the alcohol?

Comment: well, its almost 10% more alcohol. Also, green label is a blended malt, whereas gold label is a blended whisky, which means it's also contains grain whisky. Due to the higher destillation of grain spirit, it has a cleaner (and thus smoother) alcohol. Concerning smoky notes, in my experience they don't hide the power of alcohol.

Comment: Thank you for detailed and clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Johnnie Walker Green vs Gold Label?**

> **Green label** was added to the fold in 1997. Originally called Pure Malt, it was renamed Green Label in 2004. There is very little smoke at all in Green label. It is made with malt whisky only and has a sweeter more honied flavour profile and is exceptionally smooth.
>
> Gold label was also introduced in 1997, and although had no age statement, the whiskies are around the eighteen year mark. Like Green, Gold has a sweeter flavour profile, with vanilla and caramel being dominant, but there are also more complex and subtle flavours of heather honey and blossom. - [The Colours of Johnnie Walker](https://www.thethreedrinkers.com/magazine-content/2019/5/8/the-colours-of-johnnie-walker)

Although the Green Label has slight smoky notes and has a 43% ABV over a 40 % ABV of the Gold Label, I would go with the Green Label. The [spicy black pepper](https://uproxx.com/life/johnnie-walker-whisky-ranked/) notes also make it my choice, for that **”alcohol burn”** some desire.

If you want that hidden burn then go with the Gold Label.